# iOS: The proper way to display Images and long texts with scroll functionality

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm developing an app for a news website, i'm displaying the news articles using `UITableView` where each cell is an article title, when a user clicks on a cell (i.e an article), another view opens (using segue), now in this view i want to put the following:

1. The article's Image at the top.
2. The article's date under the image.
3. The article's description under the date. *(Which could be very long)*
4. The ability for the user to scroll the entire view. *(not only the description)*

**NOTE:** I have tried so many ways, i can't seem to know the proper way to implement this structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The modern solution is actually relatively simple: compose the whole thing as an attributed string and put it into a `UITextView`. The text view will automatically deal with the fact that the description may be very long, that all content should scroll together, etc.

E.g.

```
NSAttributedString *imageString = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:
                [[NSTextAttachment new] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"whatever.png"]]];
```

... and use the natural means for composition of attributed strings and for setting things like font and colour on your other bits of text. Then just `textView.attributedString = compoundString;`.

---

Elaborated example:

```
- (void)setStory:(Story *)story
{
    NSAttributedString *image = [story imageString];
    NSAttributedString *date = [story dateString];
    NSAttributedString *body = [story bodyString];

    NSMutableAttributedString *wholeStory = [NSMutableAttributedString new];

    // TODO: can you be sure image, date and body are all non-nil?
    NSArray *allComponents = @[image, date, body];
    for(NSAttributedString *component in allComponents)
    {
        [wholeStory appendAttributedString:component];
        if(component != [allComponents lastObject])
            [[wholeStory mutableString] appendString:@"\n\n"];
    }

    self.textView.attributedString = wholeStory;
}

... elsewhere, in the Story object ...

- (UIImage *)image
{
    // ...something...
}

- (NSString *)dateText
{
    // ...something, probably using NSDateFormatter unless it's returned
    // from a server or wherever already formatted...
}

- (NSString *)bodyText
{
    // ... something ...
}

- (NSAttributedString *)imageString
{
    return [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:
            [[NSTextAttachment new] setImage:[self image]]];
}

- (NSAttributedString *)dateString
{
    return [[NSAttributedString alloc]
             initWithString:[self dateText]
             attributes:
             @{
                 NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle: UIFontTextStyleSubheadline],
                 ... etc ...
             }];
}

- (NSAttributedString *)bodyString
{
    return [[NSAttributedString alloc]
             initWithString:[self bodyText]
             attributes:
             @{
                 NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle: UIFontTextStyleBody],
                 ... etc ...
             }];
}
```

Check out the [NSAttributedString UIKit Additions](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Character_Attributes) documentation for lists of the various attributes you can set other than `NSFontAttributeName`. Note that I've gone with the iOS 7+ way of asking for fonts by purpose rather than a specific size or font. That means that users who have turned up their default font size will get larger text in your app.

Comment: can you please elaborate your answer, i'm somewhat new to objective-c, top image and date under it then the description.

Comment: Sure. I'm at work now, which is the reason for the brief answer, and this is somewhere where the interface is incredibly verbose, but I'll try to get to it as the day progresses.

Comment: great explanation thanks! but can i ask what is the type `Story` in setStory method suppose to be ?

Comment: It's the object that contains your story. Replace as appropriate. If you're not doing things the object way and just fishing about in a dictionary then replace appropriately.

Comment: So i should make a class named `Story` right ? and inherit from `NSObject` ?

Comment: It's up to you. It was primarily for illustration. In object-oriented languages the assumption is that each distinct thing gets an object type but you don't need to be ideological about it if the only net effect is greater complexity.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a pod to programmatically add constraints. There is a special category for `scrollViews`, because they are so complicated to use with auto layout.

Here is the link to the [project](https://github.com/catalinaturlea/visualConstraints)

There is an example app you can take a look at, but the things you would have to do would be

- initialize your views (the image, date label and description label).
- add the `scrollView`
- add the subviews of the `scrollView`

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
[scrollView addConstraintsToFillHorizontal];
[scrollView addConstraintsToFillVertical];

[scrollView addConstraintsToAlignVerticalAllViews:@[image, dateLabel, descriptionLabel]];
```

This should be pretty simple to implement, but if you need more help, just let me know and I could provide you with some more sample code.

Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to display each article as a HTML string in a `UIWebView`.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.articleController.url];
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
[self.articleView.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:baseURL];
```